# Axios not working on DigitalOcean server after npm update?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, digital-ocean

I updated npm on my DigitalOcean droplet, now the axios post call in my authentication (log in) function isn't working. I added a console.log and know that the function is triggered, but the axios post request is not working on the live site. The axios post request still works on my localhost.

I'm getting this error code on the live site:

```
POST https://www.myexamplesite.com/auth/login 504 (Gateway Time-out) - xhr.js:175

  (anonymous)   @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  e.exports @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  e.exports @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  Promise.then (async)      
  u.request @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  r.forEach.u.<computed>    @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  (anonymous)   @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  onClick   @   main.84d90956.chunk.js:1
  l @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  d @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  (anonymous)   @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  m @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  at    @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  ot    @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  lt    @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  dt    @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  D @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  F @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  Xt    @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  Zt    @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  t.unstable_runWithPriority    @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  Ho    @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  M @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
  Gt    @   2.d105a7aa.chunk.js:1
```

Again, the axios post request works fine on the localhost. But the live site sends this error since updating npm (I think it was npm that I updated; there's a chance it was something else). Also, every once and a while I think I've gotten an error about something wrong with a Promise. But that error hasn't appeared for a while.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the new update was that it would no longer allow self certification. I had to add this to the server:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0';
```

That is a temporary fix until I'm able to get the website certification working properly. I still think there may be an issue with the new npm update because I didn't self-certify my site, I used an official certification system. Don't know why this error happened. Still trying to figure out how to make the app work again without the `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0';` in the server.